# Can not define a recursive method with let key word in F#

Tags: function, recursion, f#, let

I am learning F# with VS.

Would you tell me why compiler gives me an error FS3118 with the code below?

The "let" before sumToN is marked with red under line...

FS3118: Incomplete value or function definition. If this is in an expression, the body of the expression must be indented to the same column as the 'let' keyword.

```
open System
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
   let sumToN n = let rec f s n = if n > 0L then f (s+n) (n-1L) else s in f 0L n
   //let sum = sumToN(5L)
   //do printfn "%i" sum |> ignore
    0
```

How should I correct the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the zero on the very last line. Because it is indented one character to the right, it is considered part of the `let sumToN` block.

And therefore, the whole function `main` looks like it only has one `let` in its body and no lines after the `let`.

This is incorrect syntax in F#. If there are no lines to execute in the body of the function, such function does nothing, and therefore it doesn't make sense to have it.

To fix, unindent the zero:

```
let main argv =
   let sumToN n = let rec f s n = if n > 0L then f (s+n) (n-1L) else s in f 0L n
   //let sum = sumToN(5L)
   //do printfn "%i" sum |> ignore
   0
```